# How can I call a function after a Quasar/ Vue computed value has changed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar

I'm using Quasar 2.2.4 / Vue.

I have a computed property on an injected page that after it updates I need to call a function on that page.

```
       computed:{
       ...mapGetters( 'memberInfo', ['publicationDATA']),

     pmidText: {

     get () {
     let arr = this.publicationDATA
     let newArray = arr.map( item => item.PMID )           
     return newArray.join(",")
     **"Need to call a function and pass in the return value "**        
    },
    set (value) {

    }
```

The value pmidText is a comma joined item and is used as

```
   <q-input v-model="pmidText" label="PMIDS" @change = 'pmidInput' @input= 'pmidInput' style="width: 70%"></q-input>
```

When the value changes the display updated correctly but I need to call another function using the updated value. Is there a way to call a function based upon a property of the input? or is the computed value the correct place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to react on changes in the value of `pmidText` then the recommended way is to use a watcher - https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch

Comment: Works like a champ-- for others Watchers name and Computed name needs to be the same--